# how to exclude files while using gsutil rsync -x

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I am facing an issue while excluding files with prefix "LOAD*" from being synced from amazon s3 to google cloud storage and also I want that they should be excluded from the data integrity check as well.

I have tried the -x method which was mentioned in gsutils rsync help but the files has not been excluded and It is still checking for the the files which I wanted to be excluded.

Use Case:

- There are few big files named LOAD*.csv(GB), which doesn't change and
  I want them to be excluded.
- There are small files(kb) which will be added to the bucket every
  minute which I wanted to sync to google cloud storage from s3.
- I only want the job to sync the files which are not present at the
  destination bucket.

Is there any way in which I can achieve this?

Command:
`gsutil -m rsync -Cnr -x "dirX/dirY/.*/LOAD*$" s3://bucket-A gs://bucket-B`

Output:

```
Building synchronization state...
At destination listing 10000...
At destination listing 20000...
At destination listing 30000...
At destination listing 40000...
At destination listing 50000...
At destination listing 60000...
At destination listing 70000...
At destination listing 80000...
Non-MD5 etag ("1f46bed70ce51ad32c271f423463c1f8-2") present for key <Key: bucket-A,dirX/dirY/dir1/LOAD00000001.csv>, data integrity checks are not possible.
At destination listing 90000...
At destination listing 100000...
At destination listing 110000...
At destination listing 120000...
At destination listing 130000...
At destination listing 140000...
At destination listing 150000...
At destination listing 160000...
At destination listing 170000...
Non-MD5 etag ("46a7c3d9e894d6e6a6437a97b49815a5-31") present for key <Key: faasos-etl,bucket-A,dirX/dirY/dir2/LOAD00000001.csv>, data integrity checks are not possible.
```

The directories structure is as follows:

`bucketA/dirX/dirY/dir1/LOAD000001.csv
bucketA/dirX/dirY/dir1/LOAD000002.csv
bucketA/dirX/dirY/dir2/LOAD000001.csv
bucketA/dirX/dirY/dir2/LOAD000002.csv
bucketA/dirX/dirY/dirN/LOAD000001.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you used doesn't match the files in your directory. Try this instead:

```
gsutil -m rsync -Cnr -x "dirX/dirY/.*/LOAD.*$" s3://bucket-A gs://bucket-B
```

Comment: I tried this regex but In the output section I am still able to see that error in the output i.e. - bucketA,dirX/dirY/dir1/LOAD00000001.csv data integrity checks are not possible.

Comment: @MohitKumar, I just tried this solution with the bucket structure you represented and it worked for me. Could you execute the command like this `gsutil -DD` and update your question, but take precaution to delete all authentication credentials, tokens and other sensitive data.